# Use resources multiple language in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml

I have around 3 languages resources(.RESX) file and I would like to use them in XAML as I use in CS file with no problem.

My cs code is like this: Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString("Key")

And It's working but I need to use the same dictionary file to XAML file as well.

I made some searchs but didn't find a way to solve my problem.

The language change is trigged by another program, so I cannot set manually it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use resources in XAML with [`x:Uid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-uid-directive)

```xml
<TextBlock x:Uid="TextBlock" Text="This will be overriden"/>
```

Then you can have the resource `TextBlock.Text` which will set the Text property of any control with x:Uid "TextBlock"